# Mailchimp API login returning "bad request"

Tags: http, coldfusion, mailchimp

I am trying to sign in, using the mailchimp api, but I am getting StatusCode "400 Bad Request". How can I solve this error?

**index.cfm**

```
<cfform action="https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=462880470696&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8500/mailchimp/callback.cfm" method="post">
Click Submit Button
<cfinput type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit">
```

**callback.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>#URL.code#</cfoutput>
<cfhttp url="https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token" method="post" result="data" redirect="yes" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="Url" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
    <cfhttpparam type="Url" name="client_id" value="462880470696">
    <cfhttpparam type="Url" name="client_secret" value="909a7aab6f9b51995c931d2333d1efda">  
    <cfhttpparam type="Url" name="code" value=#URL.code#>
    <cfhttpparam type="Url" name="redirect_uri" value="http://127.0.0.1:8500/mailchimp/callback.cfm">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

**Error:** Statuscode    400 Bad Request

Comment: Might be way off the mark here, but could it be your redirect_uri? To the login.mailchimp.com server 127.0.0.1 is going to be itself and therefore it will not be able to call back to that URI. My other thought was the "code" attribute, maybe add quotes (") around it.

Comment: That was kinda what I was thinking. It can't redirect to your internal IP address. Also, did the response not return any details other than a 400 code?

Comment: It is returning code "bbb69fd33a97305f97f276db265c2bb9" in url.

Comment: I hosted it on server with new app credentials but getting same error. http://www.coldfusiondevshop.com/mailchimp/

Comment: How about if you encode the value of `redirect_uri` so it looks something like: `http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8500%2Fmailchimp%2Fcallback.cfm`?

Comment: I tried but same "Bad request" response.