# MailChimp Login API "bad request"

Tags: javascript, oauth, mailchimp

This is similar to the following issue: [Mailchimp API login returning "bad request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569769/mailchimp-api-login-returning-bad-request/29636055?noredirect=1#comment47416629_29636055)

I'm reposting with my results, as the solution on that question did not solve my problem. My app works fine when I use my self-generated API key, but when I try to use the token to verify, I get a 400 response with the following:

## Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Reference #7.c2f0660.1429044353.139e2e94

I'm using Node.js with Express.js 4.x, with the following validation code:

function getLogin(key, id, callback) {
    console.log(' mailchimp login ');

```
var currentDomain = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/api/mailchimp/redirect/redirect';
var translatedDomain = encodeURIComponent(currentDomain);
var secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var clientId = 'xxxx';

var post_data = {
    grant_type : 'authorization_code',
    client_id : clientId,
    client_secret : secret,
    code : key,
    redirect_uri : translatedDomain
};

var post_options = {
      host: 'login.mailchimp.com',
      path: '/oauth2/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'User-Agent' : 'oauth2-draft-v10',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
  };

var errors = false;

// Set up the request
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
  var str = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;

    });

  res.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log("error: " + error.message); 
        errors = true;
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
    try {
        var accessToken = JSON.parse(str);
        getEndpoint(accessToken.access_token, callback);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error: Error parsing JSON answer from the MailChimp API.');
        console.log(error);
        callback(false);
    }
  });     
});

// post the data
post_req.write(querystring.stringify(post_data));
post_req.end();
```

}

I am able to successfully generate the code, but the token is being a problem. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're getting a 400 and not something more specific, like a 411?

I'm not a Node.js pro, but from a bit of googling it seems like in Node, you have to specify all of the headers you want to send. Specifically, it looks like you could be missing a content-length header on your post request, which could be tripping up the server. Check out [these node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) for more on content-length.

If that's not it, I'd look really closely at the raw request (headers and all) because a 4xx error like that suggests that the server didn't understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: Content-Length ended up being the final piece to this puzzle! I did get some advice from MailChimp support not to encode the uri before I add it to the post data.